# SOLR 5.1 Java Version

Tags: solr, java

Using Sitecore 8.2 Update 6, when I install SOLR 5.1, it updates the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171`, but I haven't got version installed  (and doesn't seem to be available on the SUN website).

I have `1.8.0_131` installed and would like to use that. Is that possible?

I don't want to just update the ENV Variable as this causes me other issues :(

Answer (score 2):

According to Solr 5.1 documentation:

> Apache Solr runs of Java 7 or greater, Java 8 is verified to be compatible and may bring some performance improvements. When using Oracle Java 7 or OpenJDK 7, be sure to not use the GA build 147 or update versions u40, u45 and u51! We recommend using u55 or later.

More can be read: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_1_0/SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS.html

Yes, you can continue with `java 1.8.0_131`.

I don't know how you installed Solr that it updated `JAVA_HOME` variable, but you can switch it back.